# How did Danzo acquire all those Sharingan in his arm?

Tags: naruto

I was just wondering, how did Danzo get all those Sharingan eyes in his arm? Is it from the people that Itachi and Tobi killed [that night](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uchiha_Clan_Downfall)?

[image: Danzo's Right Arm]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Danzo acquired his right arm from [Shin Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shin_Uchiha) with the help of Orochimaru. This is found in [Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage Manga](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Gaiden:_The_Seventh_Hokage_and_the_Scarlet_Spring).

> Orochimaru did another implant onto Danzō taking Shin Uchiha's
>   Sharingan-embedded arm and placing that, alongside some of Hashirama
>   Senju's cells, onto that of Danzō's.

[image]

(Shin Uchiha's Left Arm)

More on [Shin Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shin_Uchiha):

> Shin was one of Orochimaru's experimental test subjects and followers,
>   and possessed a unique genetic make-up that allowed for tissue and
>   organ transplantation with absolutely no chance of rejection.
>   Together they performed various experiments, cultivating clones from
>   Shin's teeth and nerves in order to uncover many secrets of genetics.
>   At some point Shin became intrigued by the Uchiha clan, especially
>   Itachi Uchiha. As such, he began to imitate the Uchiha: adopting their
>   surname and customary clothing, as well as numerous Sharingan which
>   have been implanted all over his body. **His Sharingan-embedded right
>   arm was harvested by Orochimaru and transplanted to Danzō Shimura
>   along with some of Hashirama Senju's cells**. Some time after this,
>   Shin left Orochimaru's side and took most of his clones with him.

Comment: Wait really? I though Danzo and Obito stole them from the Uchiha members killed my Itachi.

Comment: That's what I thought before too. Then I did some research and found the real answer.

Answer (score 3):

We're not sure, but he most likely got them from all the Uchiha that Itachi killed.

source - http://opforum.net/threads/how-did-danzo-got-this-hand-full-of-sharingan.18133/

Most were stolen by Obito, the ones that weren't were used by Danzo for his Izanagi.

see - http://www.answers.com/Q/How_did_danzo_get_sharingans_on_his_arm

A definite answer can't be found, there are no official statements regarding the matter and no official source, so one can only speculate.

Comment: We do know that from Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage Manga, as other answer said.

Comment: what do you mean with 'we do know that' ? @AnkitSharma

Answer (score 0):

Danzo used Itachi to kill The Uchiha clan only sparing Itachi's  brother: Sasuke. Then Danzo took their eyes and implanted it to his arms